# IIS server farm with multiple websites

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, arr, web-farm

I'm trying to set up an iis server farm with multiple websites.
I have a **ControlServer** that should redirect requests and manage load balancing for two similar iis web servers. These web servers contain different websites and subdomains.

**Web server:**

- WebServer01 (10.10.0.1) IIS
- WebServer02 (10.10.0.2) IIS
- ControlServer (10.10.0.3) IIS with ARR

**Websites/Domains:**

- website.domain.com
- webservice.domain.com
- mail.domain.com

After installing "Application Request Routing" on **ControlServer**, I added both web servers to a server farm, changed the load balance rule to "weighted round robin" and opened "Default Website" of **ControlServer**.

The result was working as expected: The browser requests switch between "Default Website" of **WebServer01** and **WebServer02**.

Now I want to reach all websites on web servers using load balancing. Not just "Default Website". I added domain bindings and I tried to create different url rewrite rules on **ControlServer** and web servers, but they didn't work.

Does anyone know a working solution for my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On the ARR server you will want to configure a single farm that contains both web servers.  Keep the default rewrite rule that ARR creates automatically.

On the web servers you will create a website in IIS for each application you are wanting to serve.  Each site in IIS will need its bindings set to all IPs (*) with the hostname that matches the site you are hosting.  For example, the mail site will be bound to the mail.domain.com.  this needs to happen because ARR perserves the host header of the original request.